# Is Visual Studio's Remove Unused References Safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I just recently went through one of our solutions, and removed unused references from every project. There is some concern that this could cause issues (perhaps needing references of references, or not playing nicely with Nuget). Does someone know if this operation is safe? Is it possible that it could remove something that is actually needed?

[image]

Comment: I think a language tag can be interesting here. I do not even have those options in [tag:c++]

Comment: It's C# and ASP.NET. I added the tags.

Comment: so far I never faced any problem doing this.

Comment: This will remove direct references, but won't detect references using reflection.  It's safe otherwise.  For example, using `var f = new Foo()` is a direct reference, but `var f = Activator.CreateInstance("FooAssembly", "Foo")` will not be detected.

Comment: I don't see this option in my VS 2017; Is there any package or addin you had installed?

Comment: Not that I recall. What version of VS do you have?

Comment: Why can't I find this on VS2019?

Comment: For those wondering where this is; this is an extension added by ReSharper

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is safe if you do not load assemblies dynamicly from code (eg., dependency injection with configuration saved in file, xml, json..., use Assembly.Load, ...). In other case needed assemblies could not be copied to destination folder when debug/publish application and you will get runtime errors if you do not copy them by yourself.

**In most cases you do not do that in your solution and it is perfectly safe.**